# Preset participles as adjectives

Tags: grammar, present-participles, style

Can such a long turn be used as an adjective?

> Looking at a sinister, standing on the tribune and fiercely
>   gesticulating in his usual manner general, John felt terrified.

Should I move the noun (general) like this?

> Looking at a sinister general standing on the tribune and fiercely
>   gesticulating in his usual manner, John felt terrified.

Comment: No, it's not an adjective! It's gerund-participial clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct. Supplements are not tightly integrated into clause structure; instead they are loosely attached, marked off from the rest of the clause by punctuation (like a comma), and in speech by a slight pause. Like most non-finite clause, the one in your example is subjectless, thought the subject is recoverable from the matrix and is clearly "John".

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming for a humourous effect, it is possible to construct long descriptive phrases as in your first sentence, however it is conventional to hyphenate the words:

> Tristan was not your typical **hanging-out-with-the-guys** kind of guy.

If you want your writing to be taken seriously, the more conventional word order in your second version is definitely the way to go.